# Disable Middleware for Laravel 5.0 testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing

Is there any way to disable Middleware to test a page in Laravel 5.0?

I know 5.1 has "withoutMiddleware()" method, but how about in Laravel 5.0?

I have a custom authentication middleware that doesn't hook into the core user system. However, I need to disable it to test things behind wall.

Unfortunately, our server environment doesn't allow me to upgrade to 5.1, so that isn't an option.

Thanks! Troy

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option, if it's just for temporary testing purposes, is to just temporarily disable the middleware in `Kernel.php`. However, another option is to do exactly what that `ApplicationTrait` does and just build your own little method to mimic it:

```
$this->app->instance('middleware.disable', true);
```

Is all that's happening. I'm not sure if `middleware.disable` was only introduced in 5.1, but you might give it a shot.